# How to redirect all urls through a controller in tomcat server?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have created servlet and jsp webapp which use MVC. Now i want to redirect all urls starting with `localhost/myapp/` to go to the controller Servlet first so that i can filter them. Just like `.htaccess` do in apache server.

I am using Tomcat server.

Comment: there is no .htaccess files in java based web project... You need to use filters and servlet url mapping

Comment: okay i will check that out.
thanks for your help Jonathan Laliberte.